# Scraping data with Scrapy and Xpath

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I am trying to scrape data from a site using Scrapy and xpath but I am having some troubles. Here is my code:

```
class MaijiaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'maijiaSpider'
    start_urls =["http://www.maijia.com/index.html#/item/list/?keyword=recaro"]

    def parse(self, response):
        articles = response.xpath("//table[@class='ui-table ui-table-striped ui-table-inbox tablefixed']//tr[1]/td[2]/div/div[1]/a/@href")
        for article in articles:
            yield{
                'link': article.xpath('.//td[2]//a/@href').extract_first() 
            }
```

The problem is that articles is always empty, therefore it never enters in the for cycle. What am I doing wrong? I tried with different xpath strings but nothing seems to work.

Comment: That's a pretty long XPath expression. How about '//div[@class="cell-box"]/a' instead? Way less chance of an error.

Comment: How you get page source from `URL` in `start-urls`?

Comment: @leovp I tried that too but it is still not working

Comment: @Andersson sorry, I don't understand the question! I just started using scrapy so my knowledge is really limited

Answer (score 2):

this page use JavaScript to fetch data, the data's URL is :

```
http://www.maijia.com/data/item/list?api_name=item_get_list&type=ALL&pageNo=1&pageSize=10&keyword=recaro&sortField=amount30&sortType=desc
```

you can find this URL in Chrome Dev Tool

[image]

Comment: Sorry but I have just started using scrapy, what does it mean exactly? What should I change in the code?

Comment: @Giada Confortola change the requests url to this http://www.maijia.com/data/item/list?api_name=item_get_list&type=ALL&pageNo=1&pageSize=10&keyword=recaro&sortField=amount30&sortType=desc